# Processing a string of information

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a text file that holds baseball teams as YEAR:TEAM1:POINTS1:TEAM2:POINTS2 on each line.

How can I process it so that I wind up with the year, 1st team's name, and if they won or not?

I know I should use delimiter \n and : to separate the data, but how can I actually keep track of the info that I need?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is homework, here is not the solution, but just some hints:

- Have a look at the class StringTokenizer to split the line.
- Have a look at InputStreamReader and FileInputStream to read the file.

Comment: Given that his input is rather well formed, wouldn't the tokenizer be overkill?

Comment: I guess I could use System.out.println(st.nextToken(":")); and a while loop using hasMoreTokens() to separate the pieces. But how would I actually take each piece out so I can use it? (As in, be able to return the name, year, etc.)

Comment: Barry correctly pointed out that the Strings split() method also is useful here. In this case the String method returns an array, and you can assign the variables by using array indexes like myArray[0], etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the String class's [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

To split the text you can use the methods [String#indexOf()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29), [String#lastIndexOf()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and [String#subString](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

Then to compare which team has one, I would convert [the String into an int](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) and then compare the two values.

Answer (score 0):

How about a healthy serving of Regex?

Comment: Regex would be a bit overkill for this example. No need to overcomplicate the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
public static void readTeams() throws IOException{
    try {
        fstream = new FileInputStream("yourPath");
        in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String s = br.readLine();
        String[] tokens = s.split(":");
        while(s!=null){               
        for (String t : tokens){
            System.out.println(t);
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {    
        Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jo. Logger.getLogger() for a newby. Also -1 for presenting a complete solution to homework.

Comment: Logger.getLogger() is autogenerated by Netbeans... :)
I didn't check if this is a working solution, hope so.
I hope he will learn how to use this simple classes!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example found at java-examples.com

```
String str = "one-two-three";
  String[] temp;

  /* delimiter */
  String delimiter = "-";
  /* given string will be split by the argument delimiter provided. */
  temp = str.split(delimiter);
  /* print substrings */
  for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
    System.out.println(temp[i]);//prints one two three on different lines
```

Now for reading the input you can use BufferedReader and FileReader check examples for that on google.